# How to SSH into Linux Server executing Alias with Parameter using /.ssh/config file from PowerShell (Windows Terminal)

Tags: windows, powershell, ssh, parameters, alias

I can not ssh into server using my .ssh/config file through Alias from my PowerShell Profile file and run some couple of commands.

I already have working my `.ssh/config` file to go into my linux server (With Key)

- `.ssh/config` file

```
Host ubu
      Port 2200
      HostName 192.168.1.197
      User julio
```

Now I want to ssh into server using Alias from my PowerShell Profile file and run some updates commands

`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y && sudo apt dist-upgrade && sudo apt autoremove -y && sudo apt autoclean`

I try this unsuccesfully,

- PowerShell Profile File

```
Function ubuFullUpdate {ssh ubu; sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y && sudo apt dist-upgrade && sudo apt autoremove -y && sudo apt autoclean}
Set-Alias -Name ubu -Value ubuFullUpdate
```

Just go into server (`.ssh/config` work fine) and all next commands fail.

```
Function ubuFullUpdate {ssh -t -p 2200 julio@192.168.1.197 sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y && sudo apt dist-upgrade && sudo apt autoremove -y && sudo apt autoclean}
Set-Alias -Name ubu -Value ubuFullUpdate
```

Go into server but just work `sudo apt update` and the following commands fail and flag error.

Normal error message in both cases

> The term 'sudo' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check
> the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

I'm sure it's not sudo itself the failure, it's what follows from that point and being able to execute several consecutive commands

Happy Fixing!!

Comment: SSH is a command to PS and what follows are arguments. What I like to do is to make the arguments a variable : $arguments = 'ubu; sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y && sudo apt dist-upgrade && sudo apt autoremove -y && sudo apt autoclean'  Then the SSH command would be :  ssh $arguments.

Comment: Could you be more specific, that located in PS Profile or .ssh\config file? because I tryed in PS Profile and fail too!! Thank's

Comment: SSH look like it is working.  Once you make a connection you are sending string commands to the remote machine.  The local machine is trying to interpret the command "sudo" instead of the remote machine.  You need a -ScriptBlock like in this example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-7.3#linux-to-linux.  ScriptBlock will work on any connection, not just linux to linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was able to find one easy solution (because like all in IT has more than one way to do it)

> No .ssh/config file needed

```
Function ubuFullUpdate {ssh -t -p 2200 <USERNAME>@<SERVERIPADRRESS> 'sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade -y; sudo apt dist-upgrade; sudo apt autoremove -y; sudo apt autoclean'}
Set-Alias -Name ubu -Value ubuFullUpdate
```

ubuFullUpdate = any function name

ubu= any alias name